# Where does VBUS go in the RP2040 minimal design example?

Tags: usb, rp2040

What does the arrow labelled VBUS mean in this schematic?

[image: RP2040 minimal design example]

Comment: Probably nowhere, it connects the USB connector to the 3V3 regulator; it's identified as a power rail for clarity (or in this case, for confusion).  In this schematic the upward arrow symbol is used to identify a power rail.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Frog.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

In this schematic the up-arrow symbol is used to indicate a power rail.  In the case of the VBUS rail it's only connected to the USB connector, a decap and the 3V3 regulator, which are already drawn as connected in the schematic.  The symbol is there to acknowledge that this is in fact a power rail and to give it a name.